# Column with accent character

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database where I have a table with several columns.

One is name like 'Hèllo', for example.

The problem occurs when I access the results of this column. 
Example:

```
$query = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM ........... "); 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$myresult = $result["Hèllo"];
}
echo "$myresult";
```

This doesn't work because the name of the column contains the character 'è'. Are there any methods to solve this problem?

I tried:

```
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) contains both "associative" and "number" indices, so if you know that this column on the third place just try to access it by index number:

$result[0],
$result[3],

etc.

**HINT**:

1. It is better to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
2. Try to avoid such table/column names

Answer (score 1):

`SET NAMES 'utf8';` will be needed unless your connection is already UTF-8.

You also need to confirm that your editor saves the PHP file in UTF-8. In Notepad++, for example, you can check this from Encoding menu:

[image]